# C# Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path

Tags: c#

Проблема такая:

Есть program.exe. Он увидел, что вышло обновление и по указанной ссылке скачал новую версию program 1.0.0.1.exe и updater 1.0.0.1.exe. Папка с программой находится в документах пользователя.

Теперь program.exe запускает updater 1.0.0.1.exe через Process.Start.

Сам updater 1.0.0.1.exe убивает процесс program.exe так:

```
Process[] ps1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("program"); //Имя процесса.
        foreach (Process p1 in ps1)
        {
            p1.Kill();
        }
```

Теперь он удаляет все *.exe файлы в папке, кроме новых (которые только что скачались):

```
string _dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)+"\\Documents\\Program";//AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string _del = @"*.exe";
        string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(_dir, _del);
        foreach (string fl in _files)
        {
            if (fl.Contains("Program " + ProgramVersion + ".exe") || fl.Contains("updater " + ProgramVersion + ".exe"))
            {

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                File.SetAttributes(fl, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Delete(fl);
                Console.Write(fl + " deleted.\n");
            }
        }
```

Затем нужно переименовать новый файл program 1.0.0.1.exe в program.exe

```
File.Move(_dir+"\\Program " + ProgramVersion + ".exe", _dir+"\\Program.exe");
```

теперь запускаем получившийся program.exe и убиваем наш updater 1.0.0.1.exe

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_dir+"\\Program.exe");//Это запуск 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Что тут странного?

Через InstallMaker я создал установочник. Он просто копирует файлы в папку Program в документах пользователя и создаёт ярлык на рабочем столе.

Папка Program почему-то с аттрибутом Read-only (и никак его не изменить). Новые программы тутда скачиваются. Если запустить updater сразу после компиляции или из студии - то всё работает отлично. Но вот если я скачаю обновления через сервер (всё как я описывал), то не поняно почему вдруг, возникает исключение в окне консоли:

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Program\updater 1.0.0.1.exe' is denied.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)

at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)

at updater.Program.Main(String[] args)

Я не могу посмотреть точно, где спотыкается программа, потому что во время отладки ошибок просто нет. Как это лечить? До нового года всё работало (правда не было переименования файла и удаления старых версий. Просто было скачивание и запуск).

Я пробовал запуск от админа (и первой программы и отдельно второй) - результата нет.

Танцы с аттрибутами ничего не дали.

Директории менял, т.е. и с полным путём пробовал и просто с указание файлов (всё находится в одной папке).

На стеке уже просматривал подобные случаи, мне не помогло.

Может сам Windows перестал "доверять" скаченым программам? Как вообще тогда делают обновления? Может есть какая-то специальная папка, которая "не контролируется" так жёстко? Тип туда свсё скачать, переименовать и готовое перекопировать в рабочую папку?

Я просто в шоке =(

Comment: [ClickOnce?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/visualstudio/deployment/accessing-local-and-remote-data-in-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему стеку, проблема в `File.Delete(fl);` и, скорее всего в том, что процесс ещё запущен, когда вы выполняете удаление, что приводит к исключению. Суть в том, что метод `Kill` асинхронный.

Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.8):

> Метод Kill выполняется асинхронно. После вызова метода Kill вызовите
>   метод *WaitForExit*, чтобы дождаться завершения процесса, или проверьте
>   свойство HasExited, чтобы определить, завершился ли процесс.

Comment: Удалялку вообще убрал. Слегка изменил код: foreach (Process p1 in ps1)
            {
                p1.Kill();
                p1.WaitForExit();
                if (p1.HasExited == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Процесс убит");
                }
            }

Comment: Вообще ничего не изменилось

Comment: 1. Попробуйте запустить приложение от имени Администратора. 2. Попробуйте использовать %AppData% вместо текущего пути для updater

Comment: Заметил ещё кое-что. Компилирую новую версию для updater. в Assambly прописываю новую версию. Всё это дело сохраняется. Захожу в св-ва этого бинарника и вижу новую версию. Выгружаю на сервер (старые удаляю). Скачиваю и так же захожу в св-ва. И почему-то вижу старую версию. Это как так? Может влиять? С тем условием, что ProgramVersion содержит инфу из Assambly.

Comment: Т.е. вы удалили `delete`, но в стеке исключения все равно at `System.IO.File.Delete(String path)`?

Comment: Именно так и было. Создал другую папку на сервере. Теперь в св-вах бинарника нужная версия (не понимаю что случилось). Включил обратно удаление. Всё чистится. Но File.Move не работает. Попробовал File.Copy в ту же папку но с новым именем и file.delete после копирования. Теперь тут ничего не происходит. т.е. не переименовывает. Копируемый файл не запущен.

Comment: А вот если запустить в отладке, то всё как надо. Переименовывает отлично. Может можно как-то насильно запросить права админа? Вдруг это решит проблему?

Comment: Нашёл способ запуска от админа. теперь updater.exe запускается с повышенными правами, но:    
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.SetPrivilege(String privilegeName, Int32 attrib)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode()
   at updater.Program.Main(String[] args)